# Нужна ли запятая после "ведь"?

Tags: пунктуация

Благодаря мафии я научился вставать вовремя. Ведь, если ты забудешь проснуться, тебе никто не поверит.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**Благодаря мафии, я научился вставать вовремя. Ведь если ты забудешь проснуться, тебе никто не поверит.**

1) Оборот "благодаря тебе" обособляется факультативно, при этом меняется расстановка логических ударений.

2) Слово "ведь" с словарях и справочниках считается **частицей или союзом** и может соединяться с подчинительным союзом, например:

А всё-таки я думаю, что его не украли, ― сказал я через некоторое время, ― **ведь если никого не было**, кто же может его украсть? [М. А. Булгаков. Записки покойника (Театральный роман) (1936-1937)]

Обособление частицы "ведь" с целью ее выделения  ― это авторская пунктуация.

**ВЕДЬ.** **I. частица.** Употр. для усиления основного содержания всего высказывания (предположения, утверждения, вопроса и т.п.) или выделения, подчёркивания отдельного слова. В. приди я вовремя, этого бы не случилось.  **II. союз.** 1. Присоединяет предложения, содержащие указание **на причину,** обоснование предыдущего высказывания. Пора домой, в. уже поздно. 2. Несмотря на то, что; хотя.  В. говорил вам, да не послушались.